# Comparing string from bundle to local value

Tags: java, android, bundle

I've tried dozens of different combinations, and I have no idea why this won't work - the logic in it makes complete sense.

I'm passing a bundle from a previous activity which has stored the value from a spinner into a string. I'm then reading the string and if it's equivilent to whatever I specify - acting on that.

I've printed the string directly to a TextView just to make sure I'm getting the expected result, and I am - but it still won't register.

```
    TextView tv;

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv.append(extras.getString("pageNumber"));
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    int base = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("pageNumber")) * 70;
    tv.append(Integer.toString(base));

/* Here is where I'm editing */
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    String plat = extras.getString("platform");
    if (plat == "Wordpress") tv.append("900");
```

My array for the spinner is defined in my strings.xml and is as follows:

```
    <string-array name="platform_array">
    <item>None</item>
    <item>Joomla</item>
    <item>Wordpress</item>   
    <item>Drupal</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` is to compare two objects, `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` is to compare two objects' values.

Comment: Hm, must be Java specific syntax - I'm used to C++. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Compare String using `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` don't use `==`.

It should be `if (plat.equals("Wordpress")) tv.append("900");`

or `if (plat.equalsIgnoreCase("Wordoress")tv.append("900");` If you want to the compiler to look for lowercase and uppercase.

Comment: Hm, must be Java specific syntax - I'm used to C++. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is one of those places where Java is completely different from C++.

**Short answer:** use == to compare primitives, use `equals()` to compare objects.

**Long answer:** When comparing two objects, == will tell you if they're the same object. There are times when you might care about that, but they're very rare. Usually, you care about the contents of the objects, so you want to use `equals()`. And this assumes that the object's class implements `equals()` in a useful fashion, instead of just [inheriting from java.lang.Object.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

There's also an additional wrinkle with strings. Java strings are immutable; you can't change the contents of an existing string, you can only set a string variable to point to a different string object. For this reason, if the compiler comes across two identical strings, it may choose to optimize things by replacing them with one string. In that case, the == operator may give unexpected results:

```
    String a = "a";
    String b = "a";
    (a == b)  // evaluates to true
```

So *never* use == with strings.